# Calculate the shortest distance of each 1-pixel to any zero-pixel in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, transform, distance, pixel

I am calculating the shortest distance from each foreground pixel to background pixel. I tried a few options but did not work as I intended (There is a built-in Matlab function 'bwdist' gives the distance between that pixel and the nearest nonzero pixel. But I am creating my own one to give the distance between the 1-pixel and the nearest zero pixel.) Here is one of the versions I have.

Say 'Im' is the original matrix with 10x10 pixels (It was randomly created. The actual matrix is much larger than this. )

```
Im =
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     1     1     1     1     0     0
 0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     0
 0     0     1     0     1     1     1     1     1
 0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
 0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     0
 0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     0
 0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     0
 0     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0

DT = Im;%create a copy matrix of Im
for i = 1: size(DT,1)
    for j = 1: size(DT,2)
        %I want to select all pixels with a distance of 1 to current pixel 
        %(i,j), e.g. (i-1,j), (i,j-1), (i+1,j),(i,j+1) would be the case for Euclidean
        %distance. The large size of matrix (say 512x512) also makes it very inefficient
        %use four for-loops to find these pixels with distance of 1 to current pixel. So
        %I use (i-1,j) etc instead of using 
        %sqrt(sum(bsxfun(@minus,[u v],[i j]).^2,2))
        %to find out all (u,v)s with distance of 1 to current pixel (i,j).
        %But I do believe there are thousands smart ways to make this work efficiently. 

        if (Im(i-1,j) == 0 || Im(i,j-1) == 0 || Im(i,j+1) == 0 || Im(i+1,j) == 0)%I want to mark all pixels with 0 to remain as 0
            DT(i-1,j) = Im(i-1,j);
            DT(i,j-1) = Im(i-1,j);
            DT(i,j+1) = Im(i,j+1);
            DT(i+1,j) = Im(i+1,j);

        else
        %I want to update the visited pixels with the minimum value 
        %of calculated distances. Apparently, here is my problem. The code is not correct.

            DT(i-1,j) = min(DT(i-1,j),Im(i-1,j) + DT(i,j));
            DT(i,j-1) = min(DT(i,j-1),Im(i,j-1) + DT(i,j));
            DT(i,j+1) = Im(i,j+1) + DT(i,j));
            DT(i+1,j) = Im(i+1,j) + DT(i,j);
        end      
    end
end
```

Thanks a lot for any help in advance!

Comment: How about `bwdist(1-Im)`?

Comment: It works using bwdist(~Im). But I am playing around to see if the above codes can work the same way.

Answer (score 1):

> There is a built-in Matlab function [`bwdist`](https://mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwdist.html) which gives the distance
>   between that pixel and the nearest nonzero pixel. But I am creating my
>   own one to give the distance between the 1-pixel and the nearest zero
>   pixel.

I think that you don't need to create your own function, because you can still use `bwdist` for what you are trying to do. You can use a [logical NOT `~`](https://mathworks.com/help/symbolic/not.html) to invert your image and then use `bwdist`, as shown in the following example:

```
% Binary image.
Im = [
    0 0 0
    0 1 0
    0 0 0];

% Distance transform of binary image.
D1 = bwdist(Im)

% Distance transform of inverted binary image.
D2 = bwdist(~Im)
```

Outputs:

```
D1 =
    1.4142    1.0000    1.4142
    1.0000         0    1.0000
    1.4142    1.0000    1.4142
D2 =
     0     0     0
     0     1     0
     0     0     0
```

Comment: Nice find! But I am still wondering if I do it with the basic idea I gave in the question, how to make it work without bwdist? Appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by myself. Here is my code:

```
DT = Im;%create a copy matrix of Im
for i = 1: size(DT,1)
    for j = 1: size(DT,2)
            %I want to select all pixels with a distance of 1 to current pixel 
        %(i,j), e.g. (i-1,j), (i,j-1), (i+1,j),(i,j+1) would be the case for Euclidean
        %distance. The large size of matrix (say 512x512) also makes it very inefficient
        %use four for-loops to find these pixels with distance of 1 to current pixel. So
        %I use (i-1,j) etc instead of using 
        %sqrt(sum(bsxfun(@minus,[u v],[i j]).^2,2))
        %to find out all (u,v)s with distance of 1 to current pixel (i,j).
        %But I do believe there are thousands smart ways to make this work efficiently. 

        if (Im(i-1,j) == 0 || Im(i,j-1) == 0 || Im(i,j+1) == 0 || Im(i+1,j) == 0)%I want to mark all pixels with 0 to remain as 0
            DT(i-1,j) = Im(i-1,j);
            DT(i,j-1) = Im(i-1,j);
            DT(i,j+1) = Im(i,j+1);
            DT(i+1,j) = Im(i+1,j);

        else
        %I want to update the visited pixels with the minimum value 
        %of calculated distances. Apparently, here is my problem. The code is not correct.

            DT(i-1,j) = min(DT(i-1,j),Im(i-1,j) + DT(i,j));
            DT(i,j-1) = min(DT(i,j-1),Im(i,j-1) + DT(i,j));
           DT(i,j+1) = min(DT(i,j+1),Im(i,j+1) + DT(i,j));
            DT(i+1,j) = Im(i+1,j) + DT(i,j);
        end      
    end
end
```

In addition, the loop has to scan from bottom up to replace the DT with min value, if there is.